# Selection on one in an Array of JComboBoxes fires the action for all

Tags: java, arrays, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

I create an array of combo boxes in a for loop like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  ...
  comboStudy[i] = new JComboBox(studyModel);
  comboStudy[i].addActionListener(new studyListener());
  comboStudy[i].setActionCommand("" + i);
  ...
}
```

The listener is an instance inner class:

```
public class studyListener implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {  
    int i = Integer.parseInt(evt.getActionCommand());

    // do some stuff that requires i and also access 
    // to the instance members of the containing class
  }
}
```

The problem I now face is that whenever I make a selection at run time in comboStudy[0] the action event gets fired 5 times. The first time i is 4, decreasing each time until it gets to 0.

I also tried it using an ItemListener, but it has the same problem.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using the **same** `ComboBoxModel` in all of your JComboBoxes.

Each `JComboBox` is a listener of the `ComboxBoxModel` and the `ComboBoxModel` will notify each listener whenever there is a change to the data model. When you select an item in a `JComboBox`, the `ComboBoxModel` changes which in turn fires events to each `JComboBox`. This is why you see events occurring on each `JComboBox`.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I moved the declaration of the model inside the for loop and it works!